# Не добавляется класс при изменении размера страницы

Tags: javascript, html

При уменьшении ширины страницы до 320px, к тегу должен добавляться новый класс. Если ширина больше 320px, этот класс удаляется.
Но, скрипт не работает.

```js
< script >
  function resizeWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 320) {
      let element = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
      element.classList.add("mystyle");
    } else {
      let element1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
      element1.classList.remove("mystyle");
    }
  }

resizeWidth();

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeWidth();
}); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Если использовать getElementById, то все нормально работает.

```js
< script >
  function resizeWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 320) {
      let element = document.getElementById('test');
      element.classList.add("mystyle");
    } else {
      let element1 = document.getElementById('test');
      element1.classList.remove("mystyle");
    }
  }

resizeWidth();

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeWidth();
}); 
</script>
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает массив значений, а `getElementById` одно значение, если у вас один элемент с классом `test`, то можно сделать следующее:

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
```

Если нужно к каждому элементу, тогда нужно пройтись по всем элементам:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
});
```

Вижу что используете `let`, можно использовать ES6:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
Array.from(elements).forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает